# Voltage collapses in buck converter when I connect a LED light

Tags: led, buck

I have a 36V ebike battery that I want to use  to power my dynamo bike lights (6V 3W LED lights.) I put a switch and a buck converter in between.

The schematic is as follows:

[image]

1. 36V 10A Li-ion battery
2. [Motorbike switch](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002329765909.html?spm=a2g0o.9042311.0.0.27424c4dhJzyxd) with a 12V LED in series
3. 22uF 50V capacitor
4. [TSRM 1-2465](https://asset.conrad.com/media10/add/160267/c1/-/en/001511353DS01/datenblatt-1511353-tracopower-tsrn-1-2465a-dcdc-wandler-print-12-vdc-65-vdc-1000-ma-anzahl-ausgaenge-1-x.pdf) DC/DC buck converter with a fixed output voltage of 6.5V
5. 10 ohm 5W current limiter resistor
6. LED Lights: Frontal - Busch + Müller Lumotec Lyt B N plus, Rear - Spanniga Solo XDvS

The problem is, when I connect the circuit the voltage at the output of the buck converter collapses (around 2.5V shows at the output.) The rear lights of the bike are on but not the front one. I tried with several buck converters of different power settings but the result is the same.

The lights are working because when I connect a 5V battery both LED lights are on. I read about starting circuits and inrush current, so I tried putting an inductor in series with the LED but there is no apparent difference.

Could somebody give me a hint on where could be the problem? If for help there would be needed more information please let me know.

---

Thanks @vir, indeed the problem was the capacitive load. As the dymano lights have a large capacitor to store power from the dynamo, the buck converter was entering the short ciruit mode again and again.

The solution seems to make a "soft starter" circuit. I did some research but I don't know if there would be an easy but effective solution for it. Does anybody have some thoughts/ideas on this?

Comment: Could you post part numbers of everything involved?

Comment: Do you have datasheets for your buck converters and lights and schematics showing how you hooked them up?  Inrush current shouldn't be an issue unless the lights are modules with big input capacitors.

Comment: We don't know what LED lights you are using, how they should be powered and we don't know which buck converter you are using so we don't know if it is suitable for powering the LEDs. There is just too many unknowns to even guess what's wrong, so edit in the info.

Comment: If the output collapses to 2.5 , what about the input?  Try connecting the Buck then with an extra switch on the LEDs to handle the surge.  Unlikely you have a choke big enough to store energy needed. An ICL might work.

Comment: Not all buck convertors or LEDs are alike. Are we meant to guess which one you have?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I edited the question, I hope is more clear now. If you need more information please let me know

Comment: Your circuit diagram shows only one LED and ballast resistor, but you talk about rear lights (plural) and a front light. How are all of those connected? White LEDs have a higher forward voltage than red LEDs. If you simply put a white LED in parallel with a red one, then the white LED will never light up—the voltage across the LED will never be high enough to light it (at least, not until you blow the red one up.)

Comment: The led represents the bike lights together. I am not sure how is wired internally the dynamo lights, but I assume there is a rectifier, a capacitor and then the LED lights (front and rear). It is a standard dynamo light.

Comment: Check the current when you have it hooked up to the 5V battery.  You're running the regulator at 100% and I suspect the lights may be drawing more than their nameplate rating.  And while you've got the multimeter out, take a look at the open circuit voltage of your battery.

Comment: The current with the 5V battery is 400 mA, but with the buck it oscillates like a capacitor charge discharge curve and the peak is around 70mA

Comment: The maximum load capacitance of the TSRN-1SM is 470uF.  It seems probable that your lights, which are designed for a ~6V**AC** input are exceeding that.

Answer (score 1):

Are you measuring the voltage before or after the 10 ohm resistor?  That resistance is very high, considering the current you want to draw.

The LEDs, at 6V 3W, need about 0.5A.  But 0.5A through a 10 ohm resistor will drop 5V.  Are you sure it shouldn't be 1 ohm?

Comment: I measure the voltage after the resistor, but there is not much difference if I meassure if before (It seems that the voltage drop in the resistor is very low). Removing the resistor or changing it for a 1 Ohm resistor does not solve the problem.